# Jasmine unit test fails when spying on a service method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

I have an Angular module, validation, which is declared like so:

```
(function(ns){
    ns.validation = angular.module("validation", []);
})(blog);
```

The module contains two services, validator and validationRulesProvider, which look like:

```
(function(module){
    module
    .factory("validationRulesProvider", function(){

        var _getRules = function() {
            return [{
                isValid: function(post) {
                    return post.length > 0;
                }
            }];
        };

        return {
            getRules: _getRules
        };

    });
})(blog.validation);
```

and

```
(function(module){
    module
    .factory("validator", ["validationRulesProvider", function(validationRulesProvider){

        var _validate = function(post) {
            var rules = validationRulesProvider.getRules();
            for (var rule in rules) {
                if (!rule.isValid(post)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        };

        return {
            validate: _validate
        };

    }]);
})(blog.validation);
```

I am attempting to test (using Jasmine) that

- The getRules method on validationRulesProvider is actually called from the validate method
- The post parameter is run through each rule returned from said method

I have the following Jasmine test script:

```
describe("Validator: ", function(){

var _validator;
var _mockedValidationRulesProvider;
var _mockRule;

beforeEach(function(){

    module("validation");

    inject(function(validationRulesProvider){
        _mockedValidationRulesProvider = validationRulesProvider;
    });

    _mockRule = jasmine.createSpy();

    spyOn(_mockedValidationRulesProvider, "getRules")
    .and
    .returnValue([{
        isValid: _mockRule
    }]);

    inject(function(validator){
        _validator = validator;
    });

});

describe("getRules - ", function(){

    it("gets a collection of rules from the rules provider", function(){
        _validator.validate("");
        expect(_mockedValidationRulesProvider.getRules).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it("should pass the post through each rule received from the rules provider", function(){
        expect(_mockRule.calls.count()).toEqual(_mockedValidationRulesProvider.getRules().length);
    });

});

});
```

So, I'm simply trying to create a fake implementation of validationRulesProvider.getRules.  My trouble is that both of these tests fail.  If I alter the line:

```
    spyOn(_mockedValidationRulesProvider, "getRules")
    .and
    .returnValue([{
        isValid: _mockRule
    }]);
```

to simply be

```
    spyOn(_mockedValidationRulesProvider, "getRules")
    .and
    .returnValue([]);
```

then the first of the two tests pass, as the loop in validator.validate will never be entered.

Karma gives the following output:

> PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7) Validator:  getRules -  gets a collection of rules from the rules provider FAILED
>           TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'rule.isValid(post)')
>               at C:/Users/User/JS/Angular/Learning/blogsite/scripts/validation/validator.js:8
>               at C:/Users/User/JS/Angular/Learning/blogsite/scripts/tests/validator.test.js:32
>   PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7) Validator:  getRules -  should pass the post through each rule received from the rules provider FAILED
>           Expected 0 to equal 1.
>               at C:/Users/User/JS/Angular/Learning/blogsite/scripts/tests/validator.test.js:37
>   PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7): Executed 5 of 5 (2 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.039 secs)

I'm a bit of a loss as to why the tests are failing in the first instance because it seems like what I should be returning from the spy is an array of one object which contains an "isValid" function - which is exactly what is returned from the *actual* implementation of that function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @yazaki solved one of my problems, the other was that I literally wasn't calling the method under test in my second unit test.  I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to loop an array in javascript, you need to use javascript basic **'for loop'** instead of **'for-in loop'**.

The code in your validator factory should be like this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
    var rule = rules[i];
    if (!rule.isValid(post)) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This got the first test to pass, thank you.  I'm quite new to JS, so I was trying to use for...in like for each.